# 2 VM'а в рамках одного окна

Tags: c#, wpf

Предположим, что у меня есть класс, который внутри себя содержит 2 объекта, которые описывают конфигурацию:

1. Конфигурация серверной части
2. Конфигурация клиентской части

И у каждого класса есть свои поля и т д.

Да, я могу все это засунуть в одну VM, но она имхо будет большой и хотелось бы ее поделить на 2 VM'а, но чтобы конфигурация была в рамках одного окна.

Как можно решить данную задачу? Есть ли какие-нибудь контролы в WPF, которые поддерживают разные контексты?

Comment: Каждому контролу можно задать датаконтекст отдельно и все его дочерние контролы унаследуют этот датаконтекст.

Comment: Т.е один DataGrid может иметь свой контекст и работать с одной моделью, а другой свой контекст? Прикольно. Но их потребуется в Xaml материализовать с помощью имен, как я понимаю?

Comment: Верно. Придется как-то в XAML их подтянуть, да. Проще всего содать вьюмодель-обертку, которая будет своими свойствами ссылаться на другие вьюмодели, но есть и другие способы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А в чём проблема?

У вас выходит такая VM:

```cs
class MainVM : VM
{
    public ServerConfigurationVM ServerConfiguration { get; }
    public ClientConfigurationVM ClientConfiguration { get; }
    // остальное
}
```

И такой XAML окна настроек:

```xaml
<Window x:Class="Test.SettingsWindow" ...>
    <Grid>
        <ServerConfigurationControl DataContext="{Binding ServerConfiguration}"/>
        <ClientConfigurationControl DataContext="{Binding ClientConfiguration}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Если не хотите писать отдельные `UserControl`'ы для серверной и клиентской конфигурации, можно переназначить `DataContext` для поддерева:

```xaml
<Window x:Class="Test.SettingsWindow" ...>
    <Grid>
        <Grid DataContext="{Binding ServerConfiguration}">
            <!-- тут UI для показа конфигурации сервера -->
        </Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```